# MVC, make conditional output in simplest way

Tags: asp.net-mvc, conditional-statements

hi
i have a variable called isEnglish

if it is true I want to output something like this:

```
<div orientation="left"> </div>
```

otherwise:

```
<div orientation="right"> </div>
```

the following code failed to compile :

```
<div orientation="<%=isEnglish?? %>left<%:%>right<% %>"> </div>
```

I know a way which is long, by using the (if) and Writer.Write method

is there another simple way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div orientation="<%= isEnglish? "left" : "right" %>"> </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a conditional statement:

```
<div orientation="<%= isEnglish ? "left" : "right" %>"></div>
```

Or, preferably (to me at least), you would remove this logic from the View altogether and create a ViewModel. You can then put the logic in the mapping between the Model and the ViewModel.

That way you don't have spaghetti code in your View. It might look something like:

```
<div orientation="<%= Model.Orientation %>"></div>
```

Comment: you are right, but I hate to see html code generated in controller, I mean when you check the english variable and fill the view model with a string like (right), and pass it to the view. am I right ?

Comment: @Nour Sabouny - You wouldn't generate the whole piece of markup in the controller. You're simply filling wit the string "left" or "right".

Comment: ok, consider it as another question, is it correct to fill part of the asp view in the controller ? I that know in my situation I don't have to, but as you suggested, sometimes you'll find yourself obligated to do that !!

Answer (score 1):

The code you want is this:

```
<div class="<%= isEnglish ? "left" : "right" %>"></div>
```

But check out Razor if you're using MVC, much cleaner syntax.